# Pandas rolling command erases column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running into an issues with the pandas `.rolling()` function and I'm not sure quite how to fix the issue.

Here's the dataframe and code

```
dictionary = {'TimeStamp': {0: '2023-02-23 08:01:50.701',
  1: '2023-02-23 08:01:50.798',
  2: '2023-02-23 08:01:50.798',
  3: '2023-02-23 08:01:50.800',
  4: '2023-02-23 08:01:50.800'},
 'Delta_TP9': {0: np.nan,
  1: 0.8932789112449511,
  2: 0.8932789112449511,
  3: 0.8932789112449511,
  4: 0.8932789112449511},
 'Delta_AF7': {0: np.nan,
  1: -0.062321571240896,
  2: -0.0734485722420289,
  3: -0.0734485722420289,
  4: -0.0734485722420289}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)

df.rolling(3).mean()
```

The problem is, is that the rolling function gets rid of the timeseries column, TimeStamp. I'd like to keep this column. I can't figure out why it's doing this, especially since in the pandas [tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) on .rolling, there's an example with a datetime column. It works perfectly well with their example dataframe. If I apply .rolling to the dataframe below, the datatime column is preserved:

```
df_time = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},
                       index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                                pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                                pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                                pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])
```

How do I use rolling so that it preserves all columns? (or add it back into the original dataframe). Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
(df.select_dtypes('number')
   .rolling(3).mean()
   .join(df.select_dtypes(exclude='number'))
   [df.columns]
 )
```

Output:

```
                TimeStamp  Delta_TP9  Delta_AF7
0 2023-02-23 08:01:50.701        NaN        NaN
1 2023-02-23 08:01:50.798        NaN        NaN
2 2023-02-23 08:01:50.798        NaN        NaN
3 2023-02-23 08:01:50.800   0.893279  -0.069740
4 2023-02-23 08:01:50.800   0.893279  -0.073449
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking python with this command is to roll on the third observation, it goes row-wise. If you look further down in that demonstration they use the time series version with `df_time.rolling('2s').sum()` to ask it to roll up on 2-second intervals.

In order to use it the way you want, pass it a time-relative rollup.
[image]

If you do not specify something that suggests at time-frame, then it will automatically just do row-wise observation based windows.

**EDIT:** If your goal is to simply preserve the time column and roll up based on observation counts, the above method will work. But if you are looking for a more robust time series way of aggregating your data, but either adding up (summing) the entire hour or days events or taking the mean or median for a period, then the time-aware method of `rolling()` is a more appropriate way to go.